# SharePoint Web analytic report

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I asked to calculate these KPI from SharePoint Analytics:

Total Number of Visit 
Unique Visits
Page Impressions (Page Views)
Pages/Visit 
Avg Time on the Site 
% New Visitors 
% of Returning Visitors

can any one help me out how to get these values form SharePoint Analytics

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the Site Settings of the site in question and click Site Web Analytic and view the data that you are requesting.

Comment: Sorry, I know the web analytic , but my question is different I can't these values from web analytic so, is there any way to get these statistics form SharePoint logs/reports/db ?

Comment: I heard you can use the logging database to perform more deep analytics. Please check the link out it explains everything.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769360(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

View usage reports in SharePoint Server 2013 - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx

or

Get SharePoint Vitals, it can provide you all those items and more, it has a free version available.